# How can i use a find_all to look for two tags?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f2=open('gdpbycount.html','r')
s2=BeautifulSoup(f2)
for link in s2.find_all('a'):
    ltxt=link.text
    print '{\n Country: "'+ ltxt +'"\n'
```

'''Now i want to look for another tag 'td' and get the text for it and print it on the same line with the country in json format. 
'''

Comment: It would help if you provide an idea of what the structure of the html you are trying to read looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in a list of tags:

```
for link in s2.find_all(['a', 'td']):
```